# {m,n} does't match below m but matches above n. Why?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

When I'm trying to match string length by regex `\w{m,n}` it doesn't match strings with length below `m`, as expected, but matches strings with length above `n`.

```
>>> expression = '\w{4,32}'
>>> string = 'a'*3
>>> print re.match(expression, string)
None
>>> string = 'a'*100
>>> output = re.match(expression, string)
>>> len(output.string)
100
```

Why is it happens in this way?
How should I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match` matches, by default, at the beginning of the string – but it doesn’t also anchor to the end. The regular expression matches the first 32 `a`s in the second case. I think you wanted:

```
expression = '^\w{4,32}$'
```

(The reason `len(output.string)` is still 100 is because it just refers to the string that the regular expression was matched against, not the part that it actually matched. You can use `m.group(0)` to find the real match.)

Comment: If you doesn't want to match more than n characters you also add negative lookahead assertion '\w{4,32}(?!\w)'

Comment: What about string that have 32 word characters followed by a non-word character? Or starts with a non-word and followed by 32 word characters? your regex will fail in that cases.

Comment: @AndreyShokhin your approach fails if it starts with a non-word followed by 21 eord characters.

Comment: @FallenAngel: try this: re.match('\w{4,32}(?!\w)', 'a'*32+'#') - it works;

Comment: @AndreyShokhinwhat about `'#'+'a'*32`? Those starts with a non-word followed by 32 word characters?

Comment: Oh, hi, I just got back and this has two downvotes. What are all you people talking about? What’s going on? Did I get the question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must use word boundaries:

```
>>> expression = '\b\w{4,32}\b'
```

a word boundary `\b` is the zero-width limit between a character from `\w` and an other character (not from `\w`, including start and end of the string)

Comment: `\b` will not handle situations where there is no boundary characters between `\w` and `\W` characters like `32aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

Comment: @FallenAngel: Your example is wrong since `\w` contains digits too.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the input to be between 4 and 32 characters. But what about word-only strings that are longer than 32 characters? Your regex controls first 32 chars and do not care characters after 33rd. So 33rd  character can be anything.

So:

```
expression = '\W*\w{4,32}\W*'
```

means your string may start with any non-word character (`\W*`) followed by words with a length of between 4 and 32 (`\w{4,32}`) and may contain any non-word character after that (`\W*`). `*` means 0 or more repetitions and it let you have word-only input between 4 an 32 characters

In your code, since your regex test passes, it gets the length of the entire string.